# Who were some of the most powerful asuras?

Tags: vedas, puranas, upanishads, asuras, demon

Powerful here is defined in terms of "who could only be subdued with the greatest effort by Devas and Gods."

In your answer- please reference ashtadasha purana, vedas, any popular hindu epic, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It has to be the Tripurasuras.

Tripurasura (Sanskrit: त्रिपुरासुर) is a trio of asura brothers named Tarakaksha, Vidyunmāli and Kamalaksha, who were the sons of the asura Tarakasura. Tarakasura was himself a poerful Asura whom only a son of Siva xould kill.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tripurasura

> The three brothers began to perform tapasya. For a hundred years they meditated standing only on one leg. For a thousand more years they lived on air and meditated. They stood on their heads and meditated in this posture for yet another thousand years. Brahma was pleased with this difficult tapasya. He appeared before them and said, "What boon do you want?" "Make us immortal", answered Tarakasura's sons. "I can’t make you immortal", replied Brahma. "I don’t have the power. Ask for something else instead". "Very well", then, said Tarakaksha, Vidyunmāli and Kamalaksha. "Grant us the following: Let three forts be made. The first will be of gold, the second of silver and the third of iron. We will live in these forts for a thousand years. These forts built in different worlds shall align once in every 1000 years. This combined fort will be called Tripura. And if anyone can then destroy Tripura with only a single arrow that shall be the death destined for us".

[Did Shiva ever give back the power all the other Gods gave him to destroy the Tripuras?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/32999/did-shiva-ever-give-back-the-power-all-the-other-gods-gave-him-to-destroy-the-tr)

> "'Duryodhana continued, "The celestials then, addressing the god of gods, said 'So be it' O best of kings. Taking half of their energies from all of them, he became superior in might. Indeed, **in might that god became superior to all in the universe.**

It took most of the energy of all gods to kill the Tripurasuras.